# password hashes, from php 5.4 to 5.6

Tags: php, encryption, compatibility

I have an old database with users and their password hashes generated using php 5.4 with the following function:

```
   password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, 10);
```

Now i'm creating a new website with laravel with php 5.6, and I want to let the old users log in into the new one with their same credentials.

However, I understand that PASSWORD_DEFAULT is not the bcrypt algo on PHP < 5.5, but it does use bcrypt on my new install of php 5.6.

How can I let the old users login into my website without resetting all their passwords? Is this possible?

Comment: The algorithm used for the hash, the salt and cost arguments are all stored as part of the hashed value, so password_verify() will always be able to validate, regardless of subsequent changes to algorithm, cost, etc.... changes to those defaults only affect new password_hashes.... so no changes/password resets are required to login for existing hashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, 10);
```

Surely you mean this?

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 10]);
```

> However, I understand that PASSWORD_DEFAULT is not the bcrypt algo on PHP < 5.5

That's because `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` did not exist in PHP 5.4. You're probably using [ircmaxell/password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) which offers this functionality in 5.4. Also, `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` is bcrypt in password_compat.

Either way, this should "just work". If it doesn't, you had a weird and possibly insecure set-up from the get-go.